# Vitest module mock with alias paths

Tags: node.js, typescript, vitest

I'm failing, trying to do a simple module mock with vitest.

The actual function is called instead of the mock.

```js
// @mypackage/utils/index.ts
const asyncFuncA = async () => {
  console.log('real func called');
  return 'a';
};

// @mypackage/core/index.ts
import { asyncFuncA } from '@mypackage/utils';
const asyncFuncB = async () => {
  return await asyncFuncA();
};

// Test
import { expect, it, vi } from 'vitest';
import { asyncFuncB } from '@mypackage/core';

vi.mock('@mypackage/utils', async () => {
  return {
    asyncFuncA: vi.fn().mockImplementation(async () => {
      return 'b';
    })
  };
});

it('should not call the real function', async () => {
  const result = await asyncFuncB();
  expect(result).toBe('b');
});
```

If I use relative paths, in each modules and it test itself, it works.

Both my tsconfig and vitest config seem ok since all modules are correctly resolved.

```
// vitest.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@mypackage': './package'
    }
  }
});
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "./types/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@mypackage/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The path resolution don't work with relative path for some reason, I've used absolute path resolution instead in vitest config file.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@mypackage': path.resolve(__dirname, './packages')
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't able to find any documentation that mentioned `path.resolve`. I guess it depends on your stack setup. 
My packages were all under `./src` and aliased as `~/`.  
After playing around for a bit I found that this worked for my setup: 

`"~": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")`